Request for a reference covering the construction of real numbers as Cauchy sequences of rational numbers
I am looking for a book that covers the construction of real numbers in terms of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of real numbers. What's a readable book on the subject?

A know a lot of books cover this, but no books that can be called "on" this. Is that really what you want?

I am not looking for a book that exclusively deals with this topic, there probably is not one. I am just looking for one that covers the topic. I will edit the question.

Many books will cover more generally the process of completion of a metric space, because the rational numbers are a metric space, and the reals the completion of that metric space, and the process in general is the same - equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in metric space.

(But technically, you can't even define a metric space without having the real numbers. So if you were being extra careful, you'd have to define the reals proof, then redo the entire proof for the general case of a metric space.)

Hewitt and Stromberg Real and Abstract Analysis (1965) Sec. 5 is suggested in baby Rudin
